# # InfluxDB: How to add a column that's the result of difference of consecutive rows/timestamps using Flux?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux

I'm new to InfluxDB & the Flux query language so appreciate the patience! Happy to be redirected to documentation but I haven't found anything genuinely useful. I have a simple time-series data with one _measurement so far.

[image: Screenshot from Grafana]

**I want to create another column or table (whatever), which has the values that are the difference of consecutive values in the column (G_PAED) as shown in the screenshot above. For example:**

[image: What is expected!]

I have the following query to get the table shown in the first image.

[image: Flux query to get the data]

I couldn't find anything on the flux documentation, neither in the Grafana to perform this operation. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I tried using the `map()` function to create a new column, but I don't know how to iterate/index the G_PAED in flux or if it's even possible.

```
|> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _diff: r.G_PAED - r.G_PAED }))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Consider editing your question and replacing images with [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) tables and code blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the [`difference()` function](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/difference/).

```
AggregatedConsumption = from(bucket: "Energy")
    |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, end: v.timeRangeEnd)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "General")
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "G_PAED")
    |> aggregateWindow(every: 1m, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
    |> difference()
    |> yield(name: "AggregatedConsumption")
```

This will only return the aggregated data so if you need both you will need to use the [`join()` function](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/join/) (or create multiple queries on grafana)